# How to add some negative vertical space before a chapter title?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, report

If all I want to do is to tweak the vertical space before one particular chapter title, can I somehow do it in a quick way without redefining much?

I tried the following and it didn't work:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{-3cm}
\chapter{My chapter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\chapter` issues a `\clearpage` to start on a new page, and the insertion of a `\vspace*`, while necessary, inserts *content* that is sufficient for the `\clearpage` to be realised. We can avoid this by issuing the `\clearpage` manually and removing this capability from the regular `\chapter` command *temporarily*:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\begingroup
\clearpage% Manually insert \clearpage
\let\clearpage\relax% Remove \clearpage functionality
\vspace*{-2cm}% Insert needed vertical retraction
\chapter{Second chapter}% Regular \chapter
\endgroup

\chapter{Third chapter}

\end{document}
```

The definition of `\clearpage` is restored after `\endgroup` as it adheres to the scoping rules of a redefinition within a group.

Comment: See my comment to Bernard’s example regarding indented  first paragraph after the chapter command

Comment: @Sveinung: I can't replicate your concern with my code.

Comment: Try adding some text between the `\endgroup` and the next `\chapter`.

Comment: @Sveinung: [I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6s6Q.png).

Comment: Strange, because when I do that, the first paragraph is indented.

Comment: Even more strange: If you put two paragraphs of text in chapter 1, the first paragraph of chapter 2 is indented with your code. If you have one paragraph in chapter 1, the first paragraph of chapter two is not indented.

Comment: @Sveinung: I too get an indented paragraph.

Comment: The first paragraph should go inside the group for it not be indented; that is, just put `\endgroup` *after* the first paragraph.

Comment: @Werner, how about substituting `\cleardoublepage` for `\clearpage` in order for this to work with the `twoside` class option?

Comment: @n.r.: That should work, as long as you insert the `\cleardoublepage` manually before removing `\clearpage` functionality (temporarily).

Answer (score 8):

If you want to re-define the whole layout of chapter headings, you can use `titlesec` and its `\titlespacing` command. If you just want to change the vertical spacing, it's easy with `xpatch`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xpatch}%

 \begin{document}


{ %   
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
\vspace*{50\p@}}{%
\vspace*{50\p@}
\vspace*{-3cm}}
{}{}
\chapter{A higher chapter}
}%
\noindent

\chapter{A lower chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I meant I want to do it for one particular chapter, e.g. for "Chapter 3" withouth affecting the rest.

Comment: Oh! I didn't notice that. With `titlesec`, it should be possible.

Comment: @Leo: The initial code also works. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: If you put in text after the patched chapter, you will find that the first paragraph is indented, because you have put the chapter in a group. You therefore have to start add a `\nopindent` after the patch command, or explicitly reverse the patching

Comment: @Sveinung: I had forgotten to check this. Fixed now. Thanks for pointing it!