# Latex book class remove vertical space before References

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters, books

I am using the latex book classs with several chapter. Each chapter has a Reference list at end of them. Everything works fine. But the only thing I want to fix is the huge space before the References title. What I understood from searching similar answers is that the References list is generated by `\chapter*` command from the book class. I followed this question [How to remove the huge space in the Bibliography title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373441/how-to-remove-the-huge-space-in-the-bibliography-title), but was not able to modify the spaces. Note, since the spacing comes from the `chapter` command, each chapter title also has this spacing before them, but I want to keep them as it is.

So, how do I remove the spacing before the References list, without modifying any other part of the document.

**EDIT**
Okay, so from this question [How to add some negative vertical space before a chapter title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341027/how-to-add-some-negative-vertical-space-before-a-chapter-title), I got the following idea to remove the space. Instead of `\bibliography{refs1.bib,refs2.bib,....}`, I can have

```
\begingroup
\clearpage% Manually insert \clearpage
\let\clearpage\relax% Remove \clearpage functionality
\vspace*{-100pt}% Insert needed vertical retraction
\bibliography{refs1.bib,refs2.bib,...}
\endgroup
```

Now, is there any way to redefine the above block into a single command, so that I can just replace the `\bibliography` with the new command and it will execute the above block?

Answer (score 0):

`book.cls` has

```
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
```

so you can have

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother
```

and change whatever you want to change, perhaps change `\chapter*` to `\section*` is the simplest.

Comment: The spacing comes from the `\chapter*` so modifying the `thebibliography` that internally uses the chapter won't help. also I don't want to use section in this case.